# lock variable in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

I know when to use lock block in C#, but what is not clear to me is `lock variable` in the parentheses of lock statement. Consider following `Singleton Design Pattern` from [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx#_self2):

```
class LoadBalancer
{
   private static LoadBalancer _instance;
   private List<string> _servers = new List<string>();
   private static object syncLock = new object();
   public static LoadBalancer GetLoadBalancer()
   {
   // Support multithreaded applications through
   // 'Double checked locking' pattern which (once
   // the instance exists) avoids locking each
   // time the method is invoked
   if (_instance == null)
   {
    lock (syncLock)
    {
      if (_instance == null)
      {
        _instance = new LoadBalancer();
      }
    }
   }

  return _instance;
 }
}
```

in the above code, i can not understand why we do not use `_instance` for lock variable instead of `syncLock?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> in the above code, i can not understand why we do not use _instance for lock variable instead of `syncLock?

Well you'd be trying to lock on a null reference, for one thing...

Additionally, you'd be locking via mutable field, which is a bad idea. (If the field changes value, then another thread can get into the same code. Not great.) It's generally a good idea to lock via a readonly field.

Also, you'd be locking on a reference which is *also* returned to callers, who could hold the lock for arbitrarily long periods. I prefer to lock on a reference which is never exposed outside the class - like `syncLock`.

Finally, this implementation is broken anyway due to the CLI memory model. (It *may* or may not be broken in the MS implementation, which is a bit stronger. I wouldn't like to bet either way.) The `_instance` variable should be marked as `volatile` if you *really* want to use this approach... but I'd personally avoid double-checked locking anyway. See my [article on the singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) for more details.

Comment: why compiler use syncLock? What is benefit of this variable at all?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi: What do you mean by "why compiler use syncLock?" It's not the compiler, it's the developer... the point is to make sure that only one thread enters the code which creates an instance of LoadBalancer.

Comment: you need to lock on an object. that's all it's there for.

Comment: @CoryNelson so syncLock will be used for checking "is there any thread in lock block"?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi: Yes, sort of. Or rather, *preventing* more than one thread getting in there at a time.

Comment: @CoryNelson why compiler does not create such variable behind scene?

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi: Why would you expect it to? How would you indicate what granularity you wanted? (This is now way off the original topic, and it suggests that perhaps you should go back and read about locks on MSDN or in a good introductory C# book.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the lock statement much myself.

But my guess is, that it is because you can't lock the instance because it is null.

So you have to make the static object 'synclock' which is only used for locking the part where you actually create the 'instance' variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general style preference of mine - wherever possible, only lock on objects specifically created for the purpose of locking.

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html